# AAPT: error: 'TODO' is incompatible with attribute exported (attr) boolean

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio, android-layout

> I get the above error (in the Title) when i run my app, please advise; This happened so after updating gradles..
> **ERROR:** AAPT: error: 'TODO' is incompatible with attribute exported (attr) boolean.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.recyclerview"
            android:versionCode="1"
            android:versionName="1.0" >
        
            <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="19"
                android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
        
            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:appComponentFactory="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory"
                android:debuggable="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:testOnly="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <activity
                    android:name="com.example.recyclerview.MainActivity"
                    android:exported="TODO" >
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        
                        <category
                            android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
                            android:set="true" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            </application>
        </manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set a value for the activity's `android:exported`, as it is now still 'TODO' (literally something you should do).

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#:%7E:text=value%20is%20%22false%22.-,android%3Aexported,-This%20element%20sets):

> This element sets whether the activity can be launched by components
> of other applications:
>
> - If "`true`", the activity is accessible to any
>   app, and is launchable by its exact class name.
> - If "`false`", the
>   activity can be launched only by components of the same application,
>   applications with the same user ID, or privileged system components.
>   This is the default value when there are no intent filters.
>
> If an
> activity in your app includes intent filters, set this element to
> "`true`" to allow other apps to start it. For example, if the activity
> is the main activity of the app and includes the `category`
> "`android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`".
>
> If this element is set to "`false`" and an app tries to start the
> activity, the system throws an `ActivityNotFoundException`.
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to
> other applications. Permissions can also be used to limit the external
> entities that can invoke the activity (see the `permission` attribute).